# Cannot resolve keyword '-name' into field. Choices are: name, account, account_id

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Why am I getting this error and is there any alternative way to achieve the result of the below query?

Cannot resolve keyword '-name' into field. Choices are: name, account, account_id.

```
self.queryset = Model.objects.order_by(
            Case(
                When(status='pending', then=0),
                When(status='rejected', then=1),
                When(status='accepted', then=2),
                default=3
            ),
            Case(
                When(status='pending', then='-name'),
                default='-account'
            )
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Add [**`.desc()`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.Expression.desc) at the end of the [**`Case`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case), and refer to the fields, so:

```
self.queryset = Model.objects.order_by(
    Case(
        When(status='pending', then=0),
        When(status='rejected', then=1),
        When(status='accepted', then=2),
        default=3,
    ),
    Case(When(status='pending', then='name'), default='account').desc(),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this using the following approach. Thanks for the help.

```
    self.queryset = Model.objects.annotate(
            status_order=Case(
                When(status='pending', then=0),
                When(status='rejected', then=1),
                When(status='accepted', then=2),
                default=3,
                output_field=IntegerField()
            ),
            order_field=Case(
                When(status='pending', then=F('name')),
                default=F('account'),
                output_field=CharField()
            )
        ).order_by('status_order', '-order_field')
```